# Quick way to apply updated workspace tabs to existing Blender files?

Tags: interface, workflow, workspaces

I recently updated my Blender default workspaces by adding several new workspace tabs. The issue is that my older Blender project files are saved with the old workspaces, and if I want to apply the new workspace to the older files I need to go through this process:

1. Open latest version of Blender with the new workspaces;
2. Go to File > Open
3. Press "N"
4. Uncheck "Load UI"
5. Track down the older Blender file and open it.

This is cumbersome. Is there a better way? It would be far simpler if I could load the older Blender file first and then apply the new workspaces. Thanks. Blender 3.2.2, Windows 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncheck Load UI under File > Preferences and save. Your start up file layout will now be used by default when opening blend files.

[image: Load UI]

Comment: That works! I was looking in the wrong place. Thanks so much! :)